# Horizontal line and icon in one line?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to align an image in one line with the `<hr>` unsuccessfully. How to do it? Is it any different way than using `position` ?

Comment: I don't know how you are trying to align it, and where, but wherever `<hr>` fails, `<div>` with a border usually works well.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this is what you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/wBXFE/

HTML:

```
<div id="image"></div>
<hr>
```

CSS:

```
#image{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
hr{
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:110px;
}
```

Comment: Actually it does what it is supposed to do but also it destroys the layout below in terms of line spacing.

Comment: EDIT: I wrapped it in a container and applied margin bottom to it but this way seems rather like a css trickery than a *proper* way ( I am afraid It may break on tablets).

Comment: how about a `margin-bottom:` for the `hr`? if you don't want that you have to find an other way. try borders instead of `<hr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `margin` is an option.

http://jsfiddle.net/54Bjz/

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
​<img src="/" /><hr />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​img {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: blok;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}​

hr {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/PprBa/

Comment: Ofc.. it's better if you use an `id=""` for your image. You can also place the image in a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

TABLE with two cells?

```
<TABLE . . .>
  <TR>
    <TD><IMG . . .><TD>
    <TD><HR . . .><TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```